# Referencing figures that occur after the reference

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I have the following code:

```
The model is summarised in figure \ref{fig:model}.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{model}
\caption{HelloWorld}
\label{fig:model}
\end{figure}
```

When I put the figure environment early enough in the document that the figure appears before the reference in the compiled document the reference returns the correct figure number, but when I place it afterwards, as it is above, no matter how many times I compile it, I just get the ?? and undefined reference.

Could anyone please help?

**EDIT** I will try to make a MWE too but if it helps in the process of doing so, it suddenly worked when I changed the code from

```
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\maketitle                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\mbox{}
\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\include{AlzheimersModel}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

to

```
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\maketitle                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\mbox{}
\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\section*{Alzheimer's Disease}

The model is summarised in figure \ref{fig:SpectorBiopsychosocialModel}.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{SpectorBiopsychosocialModel}
\caption{Spector's and Orell's biopsychosocial model reproduced from their 2010 paper}
\label{fig:SpectorBiopsychosocialModel}
\end{figure}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

(i.e. I just copied the contents of AlzheimersModel.tex into the parent document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? That is not the default behaviour.

Comment: The second run of a LaTeX file normally stabilizes the reference information and the reference information should print the correct value

Comment: A working `\clearpage` is a requirement for `\include`. Otherwise, use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek nice one, thanks, that fixed it :)

Comment: did you find a tutorial that suggested `\let\clearpage\relax` ? If so we should try to get it changed.

Answer (score 4):

The `\include` feature requires a working `\clearpage`. At the start and end of `\include` the `.aux` files switches. The `.aux` file for the included file is opened and written during the processing of the included file. Labels also store page numbers. Because of the asynchronous output routine, the page numbers are known for sure at page output time. Therefore, the labels are written, when the page is shipped out.

If `\clearpage` at the end of `\include` is not working, then it can happen that the page with the labels is not yet output at the end of `\include`. Then the `.aux` file for the included file is closed and LaTeX switches to the main `.aux` file. When the page is finally is shipped out, the label cannot anymore written to the closed `.aux` file of the included file.

Summary: Use `\input` instead of `\include`, if the included file does not start or end at page boundaries. `\include` requires a working `\clearpage`.

Keep in mind that `\clearpage` is also used/needed at `\end{document}` or before chapters.